# tableview size adjusting while collapsing using tableview

Tags: ios, tableview

I am using collapsing header using `tableview`. When I collapse using `tableview`, `tableview` content moved to top. I want `tableview` content fixed to the screen even after collapsing. I mean after collapsing there is an empty space in `view` since `tableview` moved to top.Any Ideas?

Comment: hi, can you mention extaclty where is that extra space is get added , need more clarification on you question here..

Comment: If possible please add some code or add some screenshot of the issue

Comment: when I collapse using tableview, tableview scroll will happen so the contents of the tableview also moves upwards. So there is a empty space in  the bottom view. Could You understand my question?

Comment: Add your code in the question, we dont have super power to know what u write

Answer (score 1):

You can use Table Header View with number of row just like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

           if isCollepse
           {
                return noOfRow
           }
           return 0
      }
```

and on click of header change isCollepse and reload Section of table view